# javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found

Tags: java, spring

i have maven project with spring restful service oracle and hibernate and jpa, i am new in maven and spring development, and i got some bad error i can not find the answer and tried a lot but still got same error i am sharing me error below  help:

```
The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path
```

web.xml

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add `javax.servlet-api` dependency into you project `pom.xml`, you can find it below, you can also change the version of `javax.servlet-api`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

after Adding `javax.servlet-api` you need to add runtime, goto select project properties. you can refer below image.
[image]